# Execution should continue even one stored procedure fails in snowflake when calling multiple stored procedures and status should be logged

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to call multiple Stored Procedures in snowflake, currently code executes fine but incase if one of the SPs fail in between or in the starting stage, process should still continue to execute all the SPs listed in the definition and Status for failed SP should be logged into table. Sample code given but not sure how can I implement the error catching and conditional execution, updating status.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CALLING_SP()
RETURNS STRING NOT NULL
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$

callsp1='CALL GET_DATES_DATA()';
exec_sp1=snowflake.execute({ sqlText:callsp1 });
exec_sp1.next();

var insert_status_sp1=`INSERT INTO Premium_load_status values (Current_TIMESTAMP(),'GET_DATES_DATA','Product_Hrs','DEMO_DB','Success');`
var exec_sp1_status = snowflake.execute({sqlText: insert_status_sp1});
exec_sp1_status.next();

callsp2='CALL LOADVERIFICATION_TEST()';
exec_sp2=snowflake.execute({ sqlText:callsp2 });
exec_sp2.next();

var insert_status_sp2=`INSERT INTO Premium_load_status values (Current_TIMESTAMP(),'LOADVERIFICATION_TEST','LetCdwLoadVerification','DEMO_DB','Success');`
var exec_sp2_status = snowflake.execute({sqlText: insert_status});
exec_sp2_status.next();

return 'Success calling another SP'
$$;


CALL CALLING_SP();
```

Comment: Have you looked at using TRY/CATCH logic to capture errors, log them, and then continue processing the next steps in separate TRY/CATCH?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Status of SPs]I have done this with TRY AND CATCH block and was able to successfully test the scenario.

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ORCH_SP()
RETURNS VARCHAR LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS $$ {

```
try {
    var sp_call = "CALL GET_DATES_DATA()";    
    var result = snowflake.execute({sqlText: sp_call});  
    result.next();
    var return_msg2 = result.getColumnValue(1);
     var insert_status_sp1=`INSERT INTO load_status values (Current_TIMESTAMP(),'GET_DATES_DATA','Product_Hrs','DEMO_DB','Success');`
        var exec_sp1_status = snowflake.execute({sqlText: insert_status_sp1});
        exec_sp1_status.next();
    
    
     }
catch (err) {
    return_msg2 =err;
    if (return_msg2!='Success') {
        var insert_status_sp1=`INSERT INTO load_status values (Current_TIMESTAMP(),'GET_DATES_DATA','Product_Hrs','DEMO_DB','Failed');`
        var exec_sp1_status = snowflake.execute({sqlText: insert_status_sp1});
        exec_sp1_status.next();
                                } 
    
    
   }
    
    
} 


 {  

try {
    var sp_call = "CALL LOADVERIFICATION_TEST()";    
    var result = snowflake.execute({sqlText: sp_call});  
    result.next();
    var return_msg2 = result.getColumnValue(1);
     var insert_status_sp1=`INSERT INTO load_status values (Current_TIMESTAMP(),'LOADVERIFICATION_TEST','LoadVerification','DEMO_DB','Success');`
        var exec_sp1_status = snowflake.execute({sqlText: insert_status_sp1});
        exec_sp1_status.next();
    
    
     }
catch (err) {
    return_msg2 =err;
    if (return_msg2!='Success') {
        var insert_status_sp1=`INSERT INTO load_status values (Current_TIMESTAMP(),'LOADVERIFICATION_TEST','LoadVerification','DEMO_DB','Failed');`
        var exec_sp1_status = snowflake.execute({sqlText: insert_status_sp1});
        exec_sp1_status.next();
                                } 
    
    
   }
    
    
}
```

return return_msg2
$$;

CALL ORCH_SP();